# Плавный морфинг одного изображения в другое

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, анимация

Допустим, в начале на дисплее находится лого Wordpress, которое начинает плавно исчезать и одновременно с этим, на этом же месте, начинает прорисовываться лого Twitter. В конце процесса остается только лого Twitter.

Другими словами, морфинг изображений должен реализоваться **без использования `opacity`**, но с помощью прорисовки и стирания линий, образующих векторные изображения.

Ниже для примера svg коды лого:

### Wordpress

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" enable-background="new 0 0 126 126" xml:space="preserve">
  <path d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.7 67.6L53.5 97.3c3.1 0.9 6.3 1.4 9.6 1.4 4 0 7.8-0.7 11.3-1.9 -0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5L63.7 67.6zM80.2 94.1c10.1-5.9 16.9-16.9 16.9-29.5 0-5.9-1.5-11.5-4.2-16.4 0.2 1.1 0.2 2.3 0.2 3.5 0 3.5-0.6 7.3-2.6 12.2L80.2 94.1zM29 64.6c0 13.5 7.8 25.2 19.2 30.7L31.9 50.8C30.1 55 29 59.7 29 64.6zM86.1 62.9c0-4.2-1.5-7.1-2.8-9.4 -1.7-2.8-3.3-5.2-3.3-8 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.7-6 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 -6.1-5.6-14.1-9-23-9 -11.9 0-22.4 6.1-28.5 15.4 0.8 0 1.6 0 2.2 0 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.4 36.9 7.5-22.4L56.8 48.7c-1.8-0.1-3.6-0.3-3.6-0.3 -1.8-0.1-1.6-2.9 0.2-2.8 0 0 5.6 0.4 9 0.4 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.3 36.6 3.4-11.4C85.2 69.5 86.1 65.8 86.1 62.9z"/>
</svg>
```

### Twitter

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  <path d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z"/>
</svg>
```

Приветствуются любые решения, реализующие морфинг изображений: svg, css, js

Comment: что-то вроде такого tweenMax + MorphSVGPlugin = https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/KqRWya?editors=1010

Comment: @HamSter Отлично! Оформите, пожалуйста отдельным ответом и на мой взгляд, время морфинга лучше бы увеличить.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например с применением известного плагина [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) совместно с [MorphSVGPlugin](https://greensock.com/morphSVG)

```js
TweenMax.to("#a1", 2, {morphSVG:"#a2"});
```

```css
#a2 {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" enable-background="new 0 0 126 126" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="a1" d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.7 67.6L53.5 97.3c3.1 0.9 6.3 1.4 9.6 1.4 4 0 7.8-0.7 11.3-1.9 -0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5L63.7 67.6zM80.2 94.1c10.1-5.9 16.9-16.9 16.9-29.5 0-5.9-1.5-11.5-4.2-16.4 0.2 1.1 0.2 2.3 0.2 3.5 0 3.5-0.6 7.3-2.6 12.2L80.2 94.1zM29 64.6c0 13.5 7.8 25.2 19.2 30.7L31.9 50.8C30.1 55 29 59.7 29 64.6zM86.1 62.9c0-4.2-1.5-7.1-2.8-9.4 -1.7-2.8-3.3-5.2-3.3-8 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.7-6 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 -6.1-5.6-14.1-9-23-9 -11.9 0-22.4 6.1-28.5 15.4 0.8 0 1.6 0 2.2 0 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.4 36.9 7.5-22.4L56.8 48.7c-1.8-0.1-3.6-0.3-3.6-0.3 -1.8-0.1-1.6-2.9 0.2-2.8 0 0 5.6 0.4 9 0.4 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.3 36.6 3.4-11.4C85.2 69.5 86.1 65.8 86.1 62.9z"/>
    <path id="a2" d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Рабочий пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/KqRWya)

Вариант с бесплатным похожим плагином [Kute.js](https://thednp.github.io/kute.js/svg.html):

```js
var tween = KUTE.fromTo('#a1', {
  path: '#a1',
}, {
  path: '#a2',
}, {
  morphPrecision: 4,
  morphIndex: 5,
  yoyo: false,
  //repeat: 1,
  duration: 500,
  delay: 500,
  easing: 'easingQuadraticInOut'
});

tween.start();
```

```css
#a2 {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kute.js/1.6.2/kute.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kute.js/1.6.2/kute-svg.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" enable-background="new 0 0 126 126" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="a1" d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7zM63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102zM63.7 67.6L53.5 97.3c3.1 0.9 6.3 1.4 9.6 1.4 4 0 7.8-0.7 11.3-1.9 -0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5L63.7 67.6zM80.2 94.1c10.1-5.9 16.9-16.9 16.9-29.5 0-5.9-1.5-11.5-4.2-16.4 0.2 1.1 0.2 2.3 0.2 3.5 0 3.5-0.6 7.3-2.6 12.2L80.2 94.1zM29 64.6c0 13.5 7.8 25.2 19.2 30.7L31.9 50.8C30.1 55 29 59.7 29 64.6zM86.1 62.9c0-4.2-1.5-7.1-2.8-9.4 -1.7-2.8-3.3-5.2-3.3-8 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.7-6 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 -6.1-5.6-14.1-9-23-9 -11.9 0-22.4 6.1-28.5 15.4 0.8 0 1.6 0 2.2 0 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.4 36.9 7.5-22.4L56.8 48.7c-1.8-0.1-3.6-0.3-3.6-0.3 -1.8-0.1-1.6-2.9 0.2-2.8 0 0 5.6 0.4 9 0.4 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.3 36.6 3.4-11.4C85.2 69.5 86.1 65.8 86.1 62.9z"/>
    <path id="a2" d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: на Codepen работает (+), а здесь плагин не запускается? наверное из-за того, что он платный?

Comment: да, на smil можно, пример выше. Интересно посмотреть, реализацию на CSS или JS С удовольствием отдам галочку в хорошие руки.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, cssом что-то не получается плавность https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/ZyojQd

Comment: посмотрите мой код, анимация идет c использованием `stroke-dashoffset` У одной картинки параметры увеличиваются - стираются линии, а у другой картинки параметры `stroke-dashoffset` уменьшаются - рисуются линии Точно также можно сделать в CSS

Comment: добавил подробное описание, как это всё работает

Comment: вариант с Kute.js  эффектен, но и с другой оперы Нет плавного перетекания одного изображения в другое.

Comment: отдал решение вам. Видимо других решений (css) больше не будет.

Answer (score 8):

**Общая идея морфинга:**

1. На первом этапе показан логотип `Wordpress`, логотип `twitte`r расположен на этом же месте, но скрыт, для этого устанавливаем:

   ```
    `<path id="wordpress" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1150" stroke-dashoffset="0"`
   ```

   Отступ рисования линии `stroke-dashoffset` равен нулю, поэтому линии показаны целиком.

У логотипа twitter  `stroke-dashoffset="948"` установлено в максимальное значение, поэтому линия не видна.

```
   <path id="twitter" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="948" stroke-dashoffset="948"
```

2. На этапе анимации линии лого wordpress начинают стираться, для этого
   отступ увеличивается от нуля до максимального значения
   `values="0;1150"`

   ```
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="2s" values="0;1150" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  />
   ```

   Для логотипа twitter линии рисуются с нуля для этого
   `stroke-dashoffset"` изменяется от максимального значения равного
   суммарной длине линий до нулевого значения.

   ```
   <animate id="tw" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="3s" values="948;0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
   ```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  <path id="wordpress" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1150" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7M63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102 M63.7 67.6L53.5 97.3c3.1 0.9 6.3 1.4 9.6 1.4 4 0 7.8-0.7 11.3-1.9 -0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5L63.7 67.6M80.2 94.1c10.1-5.9 16.9-16.9 16.9-29.5 0-5.9-1.5-11.5-4.2-16.4 0.2 1.1 0.2 2.3 0.2 3.5 0 3.5-0.6 7.3-2.6 12.2L80.2 94.1M29 64.6c0 13.5 7.8 25.2 19.2 30.7L31.9 50.8C30.1 55 29 59.7 29 64.6M86.1 62.9c0-4.2-1.5-7.1-2.8-9.4 -1.7-2.8-3.3-5.2-3.3-8 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.7-6 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 -6.1-5.6-14.1-9-23-9 -11.9 0-22.4 6.1-28.5 15.4 0.8 0 1.6 0 2.2 0 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.4 36.9 7.5-22.4L56.8 48.7c-1.8-0.1-3.6-0.3-3.6-0.3 -1.8-0.1-1.6-2.9 0.2-2.8 0 0 5.6 0.4 9 0.4 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.3 36.6 3.4-11.4C85.2 69.5 86.1 65.8 86.1 62.9">
  
   <animate
   attributeName="fill"
   begin="0s"
   values="black;white"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze"  />
    <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="2s"
    values="0;1150"
    dur="2s"
    fill="freeze"  />
   
   </path>

    <path id="twitter" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="948" stroke-dashoffset="948" d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z">
  
  <animate id="tw"
  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  begin="3s"
  values="948;0"
  dur="3s"
  fill="freeze" />
   <animate
   attributeName="fill"
   begin="tw.end-1s"
   values="white;black"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze"  />
  </path>
   
   </svg>
```

**Пример без анимации цвета**

Рисуются и стираются только линии контуров логотипов.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1150" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M113.5 57.7l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 22.1l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9L20.5 48l-8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 66 116.2 61.2 113.5 57.7M63.1 102c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 102 63.1 102 M63.7 67.6L53.5 97.3c3.1 0.9 6.3 1.4 9.6 1.4 4 0 7.8-0.7 11.3-1.9 -0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5L63.7 67.6M80.2 94.1c10.1-5.9 16.9-16.9 16.9-29.5 0-5.9-1.5-11.5-4.2-16.4 0.2 1.1 0.2 2.3 0.2 3.5 0 3.5-0.6 7.3-2.6 12.2L80.2 94.1M29 64.6c0 13.5 7.8 25.2 19.2 30.7L31.9 50.8C30.1 55 29 59.7 29 64.6M86.1 62.9c0-4.2-1.5-7.1-2.8-9.4 -1.7-2.8-3.3-5.2-3.3-8 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.7-6 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 -6.1-5.6-14.1-9-23-9 -11.9 0-22.4 6.1-28.5 15.4 0.8 0 1.6 0 2.2 0 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.4 36.9 7.5-22.4L56.8 48.7c-1.8-0.1-3.6-0.3-3.6-0.3 -1.8-0.1-1.6-2.9 0.2-2.8 0 0 5.6 0.4 9 0.4 3.6 0 9.1-0.4 9.1-0.4 1.8-0.1 2.1 2.6 0.2 2.8 0 0-1.8 0.2-3.9 0.3l12.3 36.6 3.4-11.4C85.2 69.5 86.1 65.8 86.1 62.9">
  
   
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="2s" values="0;1150" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  />
   
   </path>

    <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="948" stroke-dashoffset="948" d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z">
  
  <animate id="tw" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="3s" values="948;0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
   
  </path>
   
   </svg>
```

**Пример трансформации логотипа Facebook --> Twitter**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  width="126" height="126" viewBox="0 0 126 126" >
  <path fill="none" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-dasharray="930" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M113.5 57.5l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.8 116.2 61 113.5 57.5zM63.1 101.8c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4s16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4 37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4S83.7 101.8 63.1 101.8zM63.1 30.6c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8s33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.8 81.7 30.6 63.1 30.6zM73.6 64.5h-6.9c0 11 0 24.5 0 24.5H56.5c0 0 0-13.4 0-24.5h-4.8v-8.7h4.8v-5.6c0-4 1.9-10.3 10.3-10.3l7.5 0v8.4c0 0-4.6 0-5.5 0s-2.2 0.4-2.2 2.4v5.1h7.8L73.6 64.5z">
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="-1s" values="0;930" dur="4s" fill="freeze"  />
 </path>
<path fill="none" stroke="royalblue" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-dasharray="948" stroke-dashoffset="948" d="M113.5 57.6l-8.5-11.4 -2.5-14c-0.8-4.3-4.3-7.7-8.6-8.3L79.8 21.9l-11.7-8.1c-2.9-2-6.6-2.4-9.9-1 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.7-2 1.2l-11.4 8.5 -14 2.5c-0.8 0.1-1.5 0.4-2.3 0.7 -3.2 1.4-5.5 4.4-6 7.9l-2 14.1 -8.1 11.7c-2.5 3.6-2.4 8.4 0.2 12l8.5 11.4 2.5 14c0.8 4.3 4.3 7.7 8.6 8.3l14.1 2 11.7 8.1c2.9 2 6.7 2.4 9.9 1 0.7-0.3 1.4-0.7 2-1.2l11.4-8.5 14-2.5c0.8-0.1 1.5-0.4 2.3-0.7 3.2-1.4 5.5-4.4 6-7.9l2-14.1 8.1-11.7C116.3 65.9 116.2 61.1 113.5 57.6zM63.1 101.9c-20.6 0-37.4-16.8-37.4-37.4 0-20.6 16.8-37.4 37.4-37.4s37.4 16.8 37.4 37.4C100.4 85.1 83.7 101.9 63.1 101.9zM63.1 30.7c-18.7 0-33.8 15.2-33.8 33.8 0 18.7 15.2 33.8 33.8 33.8 18.7 0 33.8-15.2 33.8-33.8C96.9 45.9 81.7 30.7 63.1 30.7zM78.5 85.4c-2.1 1-4 1.7-5.7 2.1s-3.5 0.6-5.5 0.6c-2.2 0-3.6-0.3-5.3-0.8 -1.7-0.6-3.2-1.4-4.4-2.4 -1.2-1.1-2.1-2.2-2.5-3.4 -0.5-1.2-0.7-2.9-0.7-5.2V59.1h-6.7v-7c1.9-0.6 4.2-1.5 5.6-2.7 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 3.3-4.2 0.8-1.6 1.4-3.7 1.7-6.3h7v11.4h11.4v8.8H65.2v12.6c0 2.9 0 4.5 0.3 5.3 0.3 0.8 1.1 1.6 1.9 2.1 1.1 0.7 2.3 1 3.7 1 2.5 0 5-0.8 7.4-2.4V85.4z">
  <animate id="tw" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="2s" values="948;0" dur="4s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Greensock'овский плагин конечно круче отрабатывает анимашку.

Comment: @NeedHate Да, интересней выглядит решение с Greensock, но к сожалению плагин платный и не будет работать у заказчиков без хаков.

Comment: ну это ж не морфинг вроде как. это просто стирание одного и рисование другого.

Answer (score 2):

**Пример, показывающий возможности svg smil**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Техника реализация та же, что и в первом ответе ниже,- использование анимации `stroke-dashoffset`
Пусть вас не пугает обилие цифр в патче, они автоматически генерятся в векторном редакторе при рисовании.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="535" height="523" viewBox="0 0 1070 1070 ">
<g transform="scale(1.2, 1.2) translate(75 0)">
<path id="man" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-dasharray="3915" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M72.2,211.6c6.4-4.9,13.2-9.9,21.2-10.7c9.1-0.9,17.7,3.7,25.6,8.3
 c3,1.7,5.9,3.4,8.9,5.1c-0.8,1.3-2.7,0.6-4.1,0.1c-8.8-3.3-18.7,7-27.4,3.2c-5.3-2.3-7.3-9.3-5.6-14.8M226.4,204.1c-0.2-0.7-1-1.2-1.8-1c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.6
 c-0.7,0.8-0.8,2.2-0.2,3.1c0.6,0.9,1.9,1.4,2.9,1c0.9-0.3,1.7-1.4,1.3-2.3c2,0.2,4.1-1.2,4.8-3.1c1.3,0.1,1.7,1.7,1.6,2.9  c-0.5,5-5.5,9.2-10.5,8.8c-0.9-0.1-1.7-0.2-2.5-0.4c-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.4-2.3-0.7c-1.7-0.8-2.8-2.5-3.4-4.2c-0.6-1.8-0.7-3.6-0.7-5.5 
 c-0.1-5.1,12.3-5.1,15.8-4.7c7.8,0.9,14.6,5.4,20.6,10.5c0.5,0.4,0.9,0.8,1.5,0.8c1.7,0.1,1.9-2.6,1.1-4.1c-1.8-3.5-5.2-5.9-8.9-7.2
 s-7.6-1.7-11.5-2.1c-5.6-0.6-11.2-1.1-16.8-0.6c-5.6,0.5-11.2,2.2-15.6,5.7M207.9,204.1c-4.8,2.3-8.8,6.2-11.2,10.9c5.7-0.8,11.5-0.7,17.2,0.1
 c-0.1,0.5-0.2,1-0.3,1.4c1.6-0.8,3.8,0,4.5,1.6c0.8-0.5,1.9-0.9,2.6-0.3c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.9c1,0.9,2.4-0.3,3.1-1.4
 c0.8,0.5,1.8,1,2.7,0.9s1.9-1,1.6-1.9c2.6-0.6,5.2-1.2,7.7-2c1.9-0.6,3.9-1.3,5.1-2.8c1.2-1.5,1.3-4.2-0.3-5.2M244.5,183.8c6.2-0.8,12.5-1.1,18.7-0.9c0.2-4.7-5.1-7.6-9.6-8.8
 c-10.2-2.7-21-3-31.3-0.8c-1.2,0.3-2.5,0.6-3.3,1.6c-0.4,0.5-0.7,1.2-1.3,1.6c-1,0.8-2.5,0.3-3.8,0.1c-4.6-0.9-9.2,1.4-13.2,3.8
 c-5.3,3.2-10.3,6.6-15.2,10.4c-7.5,5.8-6.9,18.9-7.2,28.3c-0.3,7.7-0.6,15.4-0.9,23.1c-0.4,10.3-0.7,21.2,4.1,30.3M191.9,264.4c4.7,4,8.2,9.8,7.9,16c-0.3,6.1-5.1,12.2-11.3,12.4
 c-0.6-0.9-0.7-2.1-0.3-3c-3.3-0.2-5.9,2.4-8.5,4.4c-6.5,5.1-9.5,4.3-19.6,4.7c-2.3,0.1-7.5-2-9.5-5.1c-1.9-2.9-3.4-2.6-6-4.9
 c-1.2-1.1-2.4-2.2-4-2.3c-1.6-0.2-3.4,1-3.1,2.6M128.9,274.7c-2.1,2.9-2.6,6.8-1.4,10.2c0.3,0.8,0.7,1.6,1.3,2.2
 c1,1.2,2.6,1.8,4.1,1.8M193.1,202.8c-4.3,1.5-7.1,6.5-6,11M194.4,230.1c1.6,3,4.3,5.1,6.9,7.2c1.9,1.5,3.9,3,6.2,3.2M115,334.8c7.2-1.1,14.5-2.1,21.7-3.2c2.5-0.4,5-0.7,7.4-0.7
 c3.5,0.1,7,1,10.4,1.7c7.3,1.4,14.8,1.7,22.2,0.8c3.9-0.4,7.7-1.2,11.6-0.7c2.6,0.3,5,1.1,7.6,1.7c4.2,0.8,8.5,0.8,12.6-0.2M101.7,206.9c-0.1-1-0.2-2.1-0.9-2.9c-0.9-0.9-2.7-0.7-3.5,0.4
 s-0.2,2.8,0.9,3.4S101,208,101.7,206.9zM37.3,234.7c0.6-20.6,1.2-41.2,1.8-61.8c4.9-0.7,9.5-2.8,13.3-6
 c11.7-6.4,22.1-15.1,30.5-25.4c1.6-1.9,3.2-4,5.3-5.4c5.7-3.7,14.5-2,18.5-7.5c-4.2,6.9-9.6,13-15.8,18.1c4.5,2.3,9.7-0.6,13.8-3.6
 c10.3-7.4,20.2-15.2,29.8-23.3c-9.6,14-20.3,28.8-36.4,34.2c17-4.2,29.9-17.7,41.7-30.6c9.8,1.4,19.7,2.8,29.5,4.2
 c-16.9,17.1-37.9,31.4-61.6,35.2c13.3-2.2,26.8-4.6,39.3-9.7c12.5-5.1,24.2-13.3,31.2-24.8c7.6-0.5,15.1-1.8,22.3-4
 c3-0.9,6-1.9,8.4-3.8c7.6-5.8,7.8-17,7.3-26.6c13.4-1.2,25.9-10.2,31.2-22.6c1.5-0.1,3.1-0.1,4.6-0.2c6.5-0.3,9.4-8.2,11.4-14.4
 c5.5,0.3,9-5.6,11.2-10.7c-10.7-7.9-21.3-15.9-32.6-22.9c-4-2.5-8.1-4.9-12.5-6.8c-6-2.5-12.5-3.7-18.9-5
 c-16.4-3.2-32.8-6.4-49.2-9.7c-3.6-0.7-7.2-1.4-10.8-1.3c-4.4,0.1-8.7,1.2-13.1,1.9c-4.9,0.7-9.9,0.7-14.9,0.9
 C95.1,4.5,67.1,13.8,47.4,33.1C39.1,41.2,34.7,52.9,26.5,61c-4.8,4.7-10.3,8.9-14.3,14.3c-4.9,6.8-7,15.1-9.1,23.2
 c-1.7,6.6-3.4,13.5-2.2,20.3c1.4,8.3,7.1,16.4,4.6,24.4c-0.8,2.7-2.5,5-3.2,7.7c-1.9,7.1,3.3,13.9,7.2,20.2 c5.4,8.6,9,18.3,10.4,28.3c2.3-3.1,6.8-4.9,10-2.8c6.2,4.2-0.5,15.5,4.5,21M257.7,77.6c15.7,19.1,19.7,44.9,22.8,69.4c3.7,28.8,7,57.8,4.2,86.7M243.1,364.7M27.8,228c-2.1,5.9,4.5,11.1,6,17.1c1.1,4.3-0.5,8.8-0.5,13.3
 c0,4.5,3.1,9.7,7.5,9c0.1-0.9,0.3-1.7,0.4-2.6c4.3,22.4,7.5,47.6,18.3,69.4c1.1,2.2,1.9,4.6,3.2,6.8l7.7,16.4
 c2.9,6,7.9,11.2,12.2,16.2c2.8,3.3,6.1,6,9.4,8.7c10.9,8.8,22.1,17.2,33.6,25.1c9.2,6.3,20,6.3,31.1,6.3c8.3,0,16.6,0,24.7-1.7
 c12.9-2.7,24.6-9.8,34.5-18.4l18.2-19.1c5.5-5.8,10.3-12.3,14.3-19.3c14.6-26,21.3-46,31.6-93.6c0.4-1.7,1.3-3.1,1.7-4.8
 c2.2-8.5,4.5-17,6.7-25.5c5.5-21,11-42.1,13.8-63.6c2.8-21.5,2.7-43.7-2.9-64.6c-4.4-16.7-12.3-32.4-23.1-45.9M70.6,207.1c3.7-5.7,11-7.8,17.8-8.8c7.2-1.1,14.5-1.5,21.8-1.2
 c3.3,0.1,6.7,0.5,9.3,2.4M55.2,181.3c6.2-2.2,12.3-4.4,18.5-6.6c3.4-1.2,6.9-2.4,10.4-1.8
 c1.8,0.3,3.5,1,5.2,1.6c9.9,3.2,21.4-0.2,30.8,4.3c5.5,2.7,9.5,7.7,13.2,12.6c-4.3,2.4-9.4-1.1-14.3-1.2c-2.8,0-5.5,1.1-8.3,1.3
 c-10,1-18.5-8.6-28.6-8.3M196.5,185.4c-0.7,0.8-0.3,2.2,0.5,2.9c0.9,0.7,2,0.8,3.1,0.8 c4.2-0.1,8.1-2.1,12.3-2.6c3.2-0.4,6.4,0.2,9.6-0.1c7-0.6,13.1-5.2,20-5.9c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.1-1,0.2M74.2,217.7c0.7-1.2,2.5-1,3.9-0.6c5.7,1.6,11.4,3.6,17.3,4.1
 c5.9,0.5,12.2-0.4,16.9-4.1M136.7,207.6c0.8,0.7,1.6,1.5,2.2,2.4c3.6,4.7,4.7,10.7,5.4,16.6
 c0.2,2,0.4,4.1,0.2,6.1c-0.1,1.6-0.5,3.2-1,4.8M157.8,308c-0.7,3.1-1.4,6.2-2.1,9.3c-0.5,2-0.9,4.3,0.1,6.1 c0.8,1.5,2.4,2.5,4.1,2.8c1.7,0.4,3.4,0.2,5.1,0.1c1.6-0.2,3.4-0.4,4.6-1.5M113.5,333.1c7.3-2.3,14.7-4.5,22-6.8c2.2-0.7,4.4-1.4,6.7-1.6c2.5-0.2,5,0.1,7.5,0.5c3.5,0.5,7,1,10.5,1.5M160.1,344.5c9.9,2.1,20.5,1.1,29.9-2.7c3.6-1.5,7.2-3.3,11-3.1M142.6,366.1c18.1-3.4,17.3-3.5,35.3,0.6M107.2,65.3c19.4,9.8,42.6,11.8,63.4,5.4c5.5-1.7,10.8-3.9,16.3-5.8
 c24.7-8.7,51.5-10.2,77.6-7.4M217.3,93c-5.8,0.9-11.5,1.8-17.3,2.7c-4.9,0.8-9.8,1.5-14.7,1.5  c-3.3,0-6.5-0.4-9.8-0.8c-3-0.3-6.1-0.7-9-1.5c-5.5-1.5-10.6-4.5-14.6-8.6M254.9,347.5c1.6,17.4,2.1,23.5,3.7,40.8c0.4,4.4,0.8,8.9,0.1,13.2 c-2.3,14.7-15.4,24.7-25.9,33.9c-11.9,10.4-27.4,14.6-42.5,17.9c-16.4,3.6-32.9,6.7-49.7,6.9s-33.8-2.6-48.6-10.4l0.6,0.4 c-11-7.1-21.6-15.2-29.6-25.6s-13.1-23.4-12-36.5c0.7-8.7,4.1-16.8,6.7-25.1s4.3-17.3,1.7-25.6M19.9,198.6c-1.2,7.2,0.5,14.5,2.2,21.5c2.5,10.5,5.1,21,7.6,31.5c0.9,3.6,1.8,7.2,4.1,10.1M251.3,319.9c0,0.3,0,0.6,0.2,0.8c0.3,0.3,0.8,0.2,1.1-0.1 c0.3-0.3,0.4-0.7,0.5-1.1c0.2-1,0.4-2,0.6-3c0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0-1.4c-0.1-0.4-0.6-0.8-1.1-0.7C251.9,316.2,251.4,318.1,251.3,319.9zM257.4,311.3c1.3-1.2,1.7-3.1,1-4.7 C257.1,307.8,256.7,309.8,257.4,311.3z">
 <animate id="tw" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="-5s" values="0;3915" dur="14s" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
 </g> 
 <path  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="12264" stroke-dashoffset="12264" d="M112.993,304.372c-3.634,0.247-8.365,1.875-11.539,7.564 c-2.591,4.646-8.661,5.387-11.495,4.451c-4.721-1.56-10.755-2.642-16.6,1.523c-5.845,4.164-12.157,1.015-11.05-6.576 c1.107-7.59,3.849-14.351,11.127-18.538c15.895-9.144,4.848-15.508,13.572-24.685c8.741-9.195,6.81-12.009,6.52-24.497 c-29.543-4.438-46.287-12.953-64.984-36.313c-18.697-23.361-25.945-42.59-27.883-71.878c-1.938-29.288-0.258-48.269,12.396-72.58 s25.977-36.014,49.065-48.153C85.21,2.553,107.832-0.354,128.742,0c20.91,0.353,34.843,1.885,46.658,8.626 c11.814,6.741,22.622,15.224,29.512,15.285c6.891,0.061,11.582-1.744,14.931-4.31c0.894,22.703-19.539,24.675-37.819,25.155 c-18.281,0.479-29.514-7.083-46.351-4.27S91.269,50.961,77.84,74.336s-13.887,31.638-12.771,51.24 c1.116,19.603,17.988,34.228,27.512,34.387c9.523,0.159,11.649-2.599,19.985-8.036c8.337-5.438,50.896-58.122,65.418-69.956 c14.523-11.834,28.854-15.488,44.328-15.678c15.474-0.19,19.428,0.335,31.908,5.45c12.48,5.114,20.149,14.533,30.211,20.291 c5.143-3.027,8.338-7.547,13.057-10.996c16.877-12.335,25.646-15.659,45.705-13.707c11.529,1.122,26.066,7.708,34.74,15.25 c15.445,13.429,28.205,32.125,38.516,46.328c8.029,11.061,17.477,24.295,30.965,28.432c14.727,4.515,25.809-14.559,27.436-25.139 c0.922-5.995,2.125-11.249,2.135-17.847c0.01-6.599-0.664-14.607-2.566-21.484s-5.16-13.72-8.688-19.394 c-5.742-9.235-15.137-18.899-24.912-23.871c-5.486-2.79-18.393-7.863-26.529-8.041c-9.969-0.216-17.564,3.133-26.781,3.761 c-11.156,0.761-31.084,3.269-39.83-5.35c-5.566-5.485-6.266-9.144-7.217-16.296c2.459,2.026,5.898,3.358,8.959,3.617 c6.986,0.59,13.527-5.114,19.166-8.419c4.645-2.723,11.223-7.589,17.324-10.048c15.676-6.32,34.932-6.138,51.48-4.445 c13.264,1.356,30.461,7.257,42.094,13.84c11.688,6.612,22.951,17.761,31.201,28.271c10.379,13.224,16.053,24.57,19.812,41.063 c4.805,21.062,6.137,52.702,0.328,73.469c-4.578,16.365-19.779,41.504-32.719,53.827c-12.762,12.155-27.498,18.022-44.256,21.231 c0.656,3.382,0.764,6.536,1.631,9.309c1.232,3.936,3.588,8.324,8.428,6.936c1.93-0.553,2.963-1.032,5.508,1.194 c2.543,2.226,1.219,10.825-5.938,14.684c-3.629,1.957-7.459,2.382-13.271,2.498s-14.883,0.141-21.193-0.964 c-6.309-1.104-10.078-6.111-17.066-6.895c-10.799-1.208-19.068-9.01-27.727-14.59c-3.613-2.329-4.832-2.353-6.914-3.53 c1.125,3.444,2.625,7.021,3.373,10.332c0.75,3.311,0.43,6.378,0.828,9.028c0.396,2.648,1.131,4.707,1.559,6.855 c1.73,1.547,2.283,3.9,5.189,4.64c2.908,0.739,7.461-0.412,10.436-0.812s4.969-2.021,7.303-1.577 c2.336,0.443,4.549,2.115,6.506,3.682s3.639,1.796,5.223,5.706s3.037,11.917,3.254,17.269s-0.383,10.183-1.969,14.43 s-2.98,6.13-7.275,10.336c-4.295,4.207-11.289,10.38-18.268,14.68c1.285,1.903,1.855,3.645,3.859,5.71 c2.004,2.066,6.182,4.381,8.041,6.56c1.857,2.179,2.799,3.742,2.826,6.186c0.029,2.443-0.09,5.619-2.074,8.283 c-4.941,6.633-10.785,7.821-17.891,10.941c1.195,7.462,2.17,12.793,0.443,20.244c-0.705,3.036-2.271,9.92-6.016,11.686 c-3.746,1.766-10.969,0.911-15.541,1.637c-4.572,0.727-7.131,1.417-10.695,2.125c-2.166,3.131-5.391,6.586-6.496,9.392 c-1.107,2.807-0.773,3.813,0.156,6.679s4.092,7.039,4.988,10.395s1.07,6.969,0.234,10.334c-0.838,3.365-2.271,5.807-5.139,8.795 c-2.867,2.989-8.508,5.336-11.318,7.758c-2.812,2.423-5.611,2.714-4.844,6.723c1.055,5.506,9.1,14.436,14.92,16.562 c3.488,1.275,8.17,0.873,12.406-0.915c-0.287,4.703-4.357,7.873-7.016,10.996c7.201-2.059,14.184-6.001,19.014-11.226 c-1.498,4.538-6.652,11.823-14.361,18.22c-7.709,6.397-7.662,5.088-11.494,7.633c6.992,1.405,13.494,1.025,18.91,0.052 c-2.969,1.637-7.836,3.939-14.283,4.616c-6.447,0.676-10.422,0.198-16.232-1.213c-5.811-1.412-11.115-6.694-18.156-10.335 c0.686,2.612,1.174,5.753,4.135,8.439c2.961,2.686,7.441,4.052,12.203,6.375c-6.062-0.688-12.432-0.896-18.389-2.209 c-4.41-0.973-7.373-2.005-10.6-3.603c-3.225-1.598-5.715-3.929-8.572-5.893c1.369,2.615,1.775,5.691,4.105,7.847 s6.117,2.959,9.18,4.44c-3.195-0.07-6.268,0.623-9.58-0.21c-3.314-0.833-6.422-2.142-9.867-4.68s-6.998-5.663-9.938-8.858 c-2.938-3.195-6.566-7.337-7.664-10.283c-1.1-2.947,0.66-5.008,0.99-7.509c-2.029,1.333-4.525,2.067-6.084,4.002 s-2.941,3.702-2.251,7.075c0.691,3.373,3.804,7.496,6.005,11.248c-6.568-5.371-10.236-7.439-11.799-13.918 c-1.463-6.066,2.322-11.572,5.199-16.159c1.429-2.278,3.567-4.398,4.903-6.597c-2.967-2.903-6.358-5.398-8.901-8.709 c-2.542-3.31-3.61-7.79-6.205-10.957c-2.596-3.168-6.088-5.173-9.129-7.756c2.673,5.742,7.066,12.785,8.02,17.229 c0.953,4.444-1.069,7.164-2.646,9.563c-1.578,2.399-4.124,2.934-6.539,4.408c-2.415,1.475-6.171,0.312-7.61,2.501 c-1.438,2.188-1.824,5.48-0.449,7.648l5.64,8.902c-2.078-1.049-5.658-4.1-7.272-6.264s-4.09-4.163-4.429-7.089 c-0.339-2.925-0.504-5.464,1.391-8.07c1.896-2.605,7.086-3.477,9.409-5.48c2.323-2.003,3.626-3.307,3.493-5.896 c-0.132-2.589-2.661-4.441-4.835-6.073c-6.637-4.978-15.151-9.565-20.787-15.565c-3.184-3.39-4.712-6.127-5.352-8.466 c-0.639-2.338,0.037-4.162,1.619-7.038c1.582-2.877,7.007-6.718,7.667-9.843c0.659-3.124-2.081-3.795-4.554-4.897 s-7.17,0.565-9.464-1.352c-2.293-1.917,0.674-5.945-1.911-8.154c-2.584-2.209-8.499-0.976-11.552-3.352 c-3.053-2.377-4.315-5.327-5.367-8.775s-1.171-7.225-0.458-9.722s2.855-2.934,4.147-4.228s2.413-2.367,0.691-4.297 c-1.722-1.929-7.365,0.108-10.609-2.369c-3.244-2.477-1.258-8.41-3.552-10.911c-2.293-2.501-6.409-1.522-8.581-2.321 c-2.171-0.799-3.023,2.02-4.355-2.438c-1.332-4.459-1.368-17.75-3.16-22.71s-5.311-0.335-6.945-5.265 c-1.634-4.929-0.085-12.812-0.821-20.257l-3.335-20.257c-11.634,7.815-19.314,10.269-31.813,12.477 c-1.043,30.582-3.916,48.591,6.464,82.52c10.38,33.928,31.387,53.924,59.726,82.649c-37.395-28.016-55.248-50.792-66.422-79.97 C109.723,356.876,111.869,332.472,112.993,304.372z M311.701,292.08c2.877,0.129,6.373,0.859,8.393,2.171 c2.021,1.312,4.166,2.384,6,4.251c4.576,4.66,8.008,10.28,9.525,16.738c0.967,4.117,1.111,9.397,1.463,14.231 c-1.385-4.468-2.316-9.127-4.289-13.13c-3.111-6.312-8.396-12.473-14.959-15.31c-2.166-0.938-3.611-0.764-4.803-0.598 c0.533,0.895,1.426,1.645,1.465,2.956s-0.254,3.876-2.477,4.954c-3.584,1.739-7.568,0.516-10.336-1.931 c-2.791-2.466-3.742-6.638-2.281-10.223C301.143,291.917,307.777,291.906,311.701,292.08z M275.629,286 c0.361-7.345,3.012-13.539,9.594-17.141c3.404-1.862,8.648-4.27,13.467-4.836c4.629-0.543,15.889-0.146,22.662,2.945 c5.201,2.374,8.744,6.07,13.311,8.771c4.566,2.702,7.814,4.513,12.162,7.543c6.674,4.651,10.586,9.772,15.213,12.842 c2.225,1.475,5.355,1.256,8.309,2.158c-2.297,0.682-5.299,1.434-7.777,0.642c-3.09-0.988-7.41-3.813-9.807-5.838 c-4.236-3.578-6.432-5.324-11.055-8.023c-2.76-1.608-7.305-3.503-10.338-5.481c-3.035-1.978-8.303-6.318-11.219-7.787 c-3.707-1.866-10.381-2.904-14.508-2.783c-5.686,0.166-13.916,1.104-18.316,5.096c-4.371,3.968-6.031,7.459-5.045,12.612 c1.646-1.896,2.742-4.278,4.391-5.688c3.416-2.918,7.336-3.059,11.588-2.506c4.777,0.622,7.182,3.381,8.76,7.916 c-1.062-0.78-3.014-2.493-4.555-3.024c-3.617-1.248-6.352-0.864-9.74,0.953c-4,2.146-2.912,5.322-3.488,8.854 c-0.264,1.629-0.879,2.941-1.318,4.412c-1.504-0.398-2.895-1.024-4.033-2.152c0.047,1.65-0.193,3.093,0.145,4.949 c0.336,1.855,1.24,4.059,1.859,6.088c-2.785-2.786-5.635-5.38-7.434-8.977C276.656,293.946,275.436,289.952,275.629,286z  M280.449,232.54c2.053-3.047,2.654-7.721,3.92-11.521c-0.506,4.813,0.467,10.106-1.883,13.592 c-2.35,3.486-6.477,2.875-9.896,3.889C275.25,236.472,278.395,235.587,280.449,232.54z M231.298,303.908 c2.636-2.134,9.75-0.428,15.071-0.047c-3.824,0.979-7.648,1.959-11.472,2.938c-0.356,1.301-0.195,2.792-1.068,3.901 c-0.874,1.11-2.534,1.521-3.8,2.28C230.154,309.562,228.662,306.041,231.298,303.908z M268.789,155.688 c3.176,1.71,7.207,3.971,10.012,4.041s3.539-1.834,5.189-2.933c2.596,8.465,5.576,17.766,9.996,25.447 c1.852,3.218,3.033,1.722,4.441,4.956c1.406,3.233,2.031,9.812,3.365,13.943c1.336,4.131,3.078,7.171,4.617,10.756 c-3.908-5.537-8.957-12.597-11.135-17.205c-2.176-4.607-0.783-5.008-2.545-9.396s-5.324-11.228-7.986-16.842 c-1.906,0.253-4.266,0.6-5.715,0.153c-1.449-0.447-1.16-1.988-2.469-2.984c-1.311-0.996-3.514-0.61-5.35-2.2 C269.373,161.835,268.955,158.574,268.789,155.688z M251.688,197.457c2.989-0.262,6.701,0.539,9.5,0.38s4.797-0.885,7.196-1.328 c-0.445-4.216-0.023-11.962-3.915-14.777c-2.514-1.818-12.839-0.449-15.597,0.146c-6.206,1.338-13.433,5.042-19.435,7.358 c5.752-4.018,10.721-7.742,17.62-9.816c4.147-1.247,13.825-2.868,18.105-1.712c1.954,0.527,2.349,1.336,3.534,2.992 c4.074,5.688,4.062,10.604,5.119,17.23c1.039,1.619,2.146,2.699,2.988,4.369c0.84,1.67,1.316,4.298,1.551,6.446 c-1.066-1.546-0.414-3.485-3.367-4.636c-2.955-1.151-7.479-0.076-11.46,0.34c2.902,2.094,4.344,4.111,4.455,8.538 c0.13,5.198-4.271,8.939-8.866,9.295c-6.379,0.495-9.668-0.906-12.248-6.358c-1.13-2.388-0.311-5.261-0.405-7.589 c-7.665,0.533-7.54,0.283-13.142,4.954c3.045,4.461,4.963,7.026,9.995,9.695c2.822,1.498,6.017,2.954,9.514,3.549 c3.498,0.595,9.235,1.17,12.909,0.606c3.675-0.564,5.757-1.613,8.481-4.132c2.725-2.52,2.975-6.128,4.039-8.98 c-0.242,2.745-0.557,6.241-1.576,8.232c-3.1,6.053-8.461,7.847-14.862,7.867c-6.144,0.02-13.744-1.397-19.46-3.767 c-4.57-1.894-12.146-7.258-13.944-11.918c-1.229-3.184-0.256-7.091-0.385-10.637c6.328-4.208,7.894-3.173,15.381-4.405 C246.545,198.883,248.699,197.72,251.688,197.457z M214.827,168.956c0.178-2.521,0.457-2.467,0.686-3.701 c-5.765-1.542-8.077,2.198-11.457,9.144c-1.265,2.599-0.013,4.146-1.37,5.857c-1.355,1.711-3.539,1.471-5.74,3.114 c-2.201,1.642-4.382,4.787-6.44,6.488c-4.223,3.491-9.931,5.622-14.829,7.971c3.345-2.468,9.836-6.211,11.936-9.797 c1.114-1.901,0.949-5.486,2.683-7.195c1.733-1.71,2.34-2.893,4.578-3.329c2.238-0.436,1.338-3.03,2.06-5.092 c0.722-2.062,2.16-3.526,3.69-5.586s3.46-5.153,6.481-6.276c3.021-1.124,7.732,0.091,10.019-0.556 c2.286-0.647,0.973-2.309,2.634-3.307c1.663-0.998,4.896-0.558,7.117-1.625c3.937-1.893,5.82-5.053,8.188-8.436 c0.344,7.282,0.26,12.525-2.357,19.376c-2.947,7.711-5.934,12.253-14.298,16.995c-2.882,1.633-5.75,2.2-8.139,3.057 c1.393-1.9,3.387-2.725,4.18-5.7C215.24,177.381,214.649,171.478,214.827,168.956z M349.865,204.463 c-3.977,0.259-4.92-0.264-8.102,1.98c1.725,2.684,3.449,5.368,5.172,8.052C346.783,209.197,347.299,208.135,349.865,204.463z  M339.445,200.613c5.508-2.346,10.307-4.244,16.299-4.619c2.402-0.151,6.131,0.221,8.557,0.331 c2.066-3.042,4.699-5.441,5.664-8.913c0.639-2.303,0.324-12.992-0.807-15.767c-3.295-8.076-6.498-8.417-11.033-13.043 c-3.291-3.355-3.422-8.464-4.406-14.189c-0.361-2.103-1.393-4.764-1.877-6.934c-5.928-0.999-12.303-1.328-19.123-0.987 c3.307-3.172,6.504-6.07,7.453-10.832c0.947-4.762,0.176-10.617-2.531-14.887c-2.707-4.27-7.031-7.99-11-11.469 c-3.971-3.479-9.662-6.351-13.424-9.197c4.893-1.752,9.889-4.326,14.682-5.255c12.486-2.422,23.244,1.282,35.287,8.563 c7.002,4.235,12.793,8.258,20.113,15.921c7.318,7.662,16.395,21.717,23.48,30.052s12.805,14.927,18.986,19.898 c6.182,4.972,11.777,6.388,17.664,9.581l9.176,9.744l7.426-9.189l11.949,1.351l2.469-13.412l10.967-3.005l-1.789-18.08 l7.885-5.596l-5.926-11.249l6.021-12.292l-7.85-14.051l3.027-13.529l-9.088-7.745l-1.186-14.377l-12.678-4.836l-5.086-12.508 l-14.254-0.16l-6.992-9.285l-9.596,0.672l-10.697-1.165l-6.049-4.466l-8.779,5.828l-10.623-5.539l-21.117,8.017l13.766-11.972 l14.262-2.278l10.926-2.785l14.756,4.846l12.988-3.29l12.523,7.403l13.252-0.733l6.51,11.681l13.195,1.523l7.139,12.987 l8.299,4.531l2.203,16.637l7.391,7.01l-3.25,14.557l8.707,11.024l-8.164,11.812l8.73,7.383l-11.16,9.891l11.303,11.771 l-13.65,4.402l8.891,12.625l-11.15,1.924l7.312,13.882l-12.566-0.167l6.33,10.398l-13.783-1.659l3.297,14.959l-10.416-9.163 l-3.568,18.13l-7.188-13.018l-3.893,16.237l-8.873-11.973L455,219.596l-9.807-15.309c2.068,8.686,1.654,18.197,7.359,26.386 c17.676-2.392,29.229-6.846,42.771-19.877c12.334-11.868,27.076-36.613,31.068-52.308c4.555-17.91,4.695-50.85,0.209-69.084 c-4.318-17.556-9.93-25.942-19.957-40.268c-9.584-10.179-19.01-20.932-31.174-28.191C457.613,10.29,434.717,7.417,414.367,7.694 c-11.268,0.154-18.816,2.318-25.553,4.768c-11.781,4.284-21.203,13.629-33.18,18.247c-3.906,1.505-7.037,1.552-10.113-0.091 c3.012,6.026,6.289,8.729,13.801,10.922c5.434,1.586,18.4,0.583,27.326-0.241c9.582-0.885,14.58-3.734,27.621-3.555 c12.736,0.175,22.828,5.013,28.346,8.168c11.385,6.51,19.549,13.732,26.643,25.172c3.896,6.282,6.625,13.37,8.547,20.603 c1.922,7.233,2.764,15.334,2.887,22.415c0.123,7.081-0.418,13.402-2.15,19.774c-4.051,14.918-12.988,30.098-31.346,27.753 c-11.234-1.436-28.17-22.522-33.842-30.258c-11.445-15.613-23.221-32.89-37.602-45.892c-8.768-7.925-20.773-13.379-32.562-14.458 c-22.117-2.024-28.676,2.177-45.324,15.899c3.387,1.08,6.693,1.676,10.164,3.24c7.703,3.471,14.748,7.957,20.893,13.711 c6.439,6.031,9.328,9.848,9.557,18.484c0.152,5.735-4.566,10.333-8.891,14.469c-2.646,2.533-6.148,4.852-8.291,6.818 c-2.84,2.609-6.357,5.463-2.789,9.619c1.342,1.562,3.672,2.74,5.637,4.199c3.119,2.315,1.691,10.919-2.418,13.201 c-5.258,2.917-11.541,2.591-15.877-1.314c5.473-0.819,8.949-1.545,8.807-6.022c-0.082-2.595-3.381-4.751-6.619-6.227 c-7.809-3.56-13.707-3.035-21.479-8.627c-7.85-5.651-8.023-8.745-10.145-17.617c-3.785,0.396-7.27,0.483-12.331,2.159 c-5.061,1.675-10.654,5.663-15.249,6.65c-11.572,2.49-13.878,1.752-20.211,0.113c-11.15-2.886-25.668,2.055-40.09,6.668 c-2.398,0.767-12.097,0.026-18.626,2.317c-10.084,3.538-24.233,12.106-32.405,18.988c-12.382,10.429-28.654,41.64-37.848,77.464 c-0.966,10.89,2.131,18.227-4.729,23.546c-6.86,5.319-6.67,18.946-8.996,22.768c-2.326,3.821-5.019,2.132-10.026,7.499 c-5.007,5.367-7.556,4.47-7.43,14.618c4.315-2.837,10.606-6.135,16.13-6.334c4.892-0.177,4.944,6.264,17.5-6.149 c6.715-6.641,19.616-6.844,28.567-9.773c8.952-2.929,25.083-8.965,41.239-27.027c16.156-18.062,23.887-37.077,27.02-64.567 c0.499,4.874,1.365,10.371-0.722,23.816s-6.585,28.546,2.891,46.634l5.904,11.269c-3.515-4.797-10.381-12.622-12.448-18.198 l-4.768-12.863c-10.667,16.748-13.119,19.744-27.937,31.743c-0.59,7.444-0.735,15.208,1.698,22.331 c2.433,7.122-1.445,15.332,0.406,20.023s6.132,2.021,7.53,6.77s-0.73,14.138,1.438,18.767c2.168,4.629,7.487,1.82,10.065,3.315 c2.578,1.496,3.421,3.546,4.8,5.513c1.378,1.966-0.539,6.614,2.265,8.123c2.803,1.51,7.176,0.231,10.093,1.68 c2.917,1.449,3.36,4.932,2.661,8.053c-0.7,3.121-3.817,4.553-5.186,7.726c-1.368,3.174-1.215,5.383,0.429,8.297 c1.644,2.915,5.284,4.52,8.912,5.991c3.628,1.471,8.726,0.645,12.47,2.679c3.744,2.034,7.109,6.087,9.086,9.033 c1.977,2.945,2.526,5.023,2.425,8.12c-0.102,3.096-1.358,6.663-3.011,9.654s-5.3,6.631,0.394,12.343 c5.694,5.711,5.484,3.249,8.746,6.954c-0.355-6.409-3.003-11.63-1.067-16.455c1.937-4.825,7.752-5.664,10.817-7.834 c3.065-2.171,4.83-5.153,7.246-7.729c-0.035,3.315,0.32,6.879-0.057,9.375c-0.768,5.075-2.266,9.58,5.297,10.394 c3.407,0.366,6.642-1.843,10.227-3.169c-1.878,3.363-5.144,6.067-5.635,10.092c-0.491,4.023,0.099,8.443,2.885,12.436 c2.787,3.991,7.599,6.955,11.125,9.301c3.525,2.347,5.414,2.535,8.123,3.804c0.133,3.956-0.646,8.143-0.195,11.869 s1.625,7.024,3.779,10.104c2.156,3.081,5.613,4.848,8.869,7.126c-1.785-4.157-5.406-8.101-5.357-12.471 c0.049-4.369,1.359-7.466,5.621-11.343c4.262-3.878,14.24-7.241,18.945-11.011c4.705-3.771,6.223-6.081,7.912-9.742 s1.219-9.559,1.531-12.85c1.549,4.61,1.77,6.043,2.273,10.866c0.506,4.824-2.811,11.59-4.215,15.161 c5.82-2.811,9.514-7.304,11.379-11.695c1.248,0.74,0.619,2.769,1.078,6.679c2.074-2.064,4.432-3.652,6.52-5.6 c2.09-1.946,4.379-3.658,5.416-6.375c1.035-2.717,0.611-5.606-0.16-8.763s-4.299-6.818-6.199-10.271 c-1.898-3.452,0.336-6.841,0.207-11.001c-3.801-0.653-7.029-2.589-11.398-1.96c-4.371,0.628-9.377,5.533-13.844,5.59 s-6.975-4.128-10.637-5.278s-7.367-1.024-11.049-1.536c4.664-4.468,22.766-6.596,35.148-8.615 c10.895-1.777,21.707-2.804,32.746-2.959c4.93-0.07,11.266,1.558,14.689,0.574c3.426-0.982,2.695-3.315,3.711-5.858 c2.842-7.108,1.441-13.438-0.105-20.596c-9.91-1.162-20.236-2.584-30.221-1.817c-9.762,0.75-21.322,5.391-31.391,5.705 c-8.754,0.272-21.717-1.677-29.234-6.259c-9.186-5.599-16.293-17.624-18.816-21.485c-4.109-6.289-9.292-18.627-12.446-24.268 c-3.152-5.641-3.847-7.219-6.47-9.574c-2.623-2.354-6.216-2.536-9.323-3.805c3.582,0.366,7.493-0.768,10.747,1.098 c4.889,2.805,10.361,14.431,13.403,19.49c3.223-10.804,2.471-15.052,11.797-21.144c-7.516,8.424-7.703,14.805-9.535,24.723 c6.25,10.258,14.939,26.598,26.309,31.132c4.107,1.639,11.16,2.667,15.6,3.216c13.818,1.711,27.146-2.668,40.717-6.019 c9.92-2.45,19.986-1.463,32.051-0.754c4.096,0.24,13.754-2.224,15.754-6.367c1.08-2.235,1-4.921-0.551-7.303 c-1.553-2.382-5.689-3.534-7.906-5.678s-3.492-4.689-5.238-7.034c-9.215,1.768-16.795,2.447-23.635,2.633 c4.906-2.021,9.613-3.174,14.719-5.171s10.904-5.275,15.025-7.995c4.121-2.721,6.752-4.299,9.734-7.465 c2.98-3.168,6.803-6.431,9-10.303c2.199-3.872,2.539-8.203,2.662-12.995c0.123-4.791-0.084-11.514-1.932-15.374 c-1.846-3.859-5.406-5.03-8.266-5.943c-2.861-0.913-4.82,1.396-7.795,1.708c-2.977,0.312-5.758,2.188-10.062,0.164 s-9.406-6.144-13.758-12.259c-4.35-6.116-7.461-16.112-11.896-23.802c-7.645-13.256-17.172-25.639-26.283-37.922 c-0.75-3.029-1.877-7.215-2.252-11.324c-0.654-7.16-0.777-14.598,1.445-21.578c1.703-5.347,4.18-10.995,9.779-13.188 c2.24-0.878,5.074-1.226,7.076-0.484c2.004,0.741,3.969,3.002,3.182,5.614c-0.865,2.872-2.855,2.95-4.207,4.4 c-2.295,2.46-3.213,4.265-4.08,7.332c2.48-0.04,5.832-0.229,7.869,0.307c2.658,0.7,5.133,2.462,6.482,6.228 c-3.172-2.813-4.748-4.104-8.707-4.204c-1.814-0.045-4.018,0.604-6.025,0.906c-0.75,2.44-1.191,5.432-2.25,7.32 s-3.121,1.435-3.895,3.641C339.1,194.132,339.055,197.718,339.445,200.613z M367.16,197.306c1.215,0.479,1.678,0.584,3.217,1.755 s3.662,2.34,4.881,5.138c1.221,2.799,1.164,7.127,0.904,8.89c-1.07-0.314-2.529-0.102-3.639-1.051 c-1.107-0.949-1.768-3.098-3.188-4.018c-1.422-0.919-2.607-0.718-4.178-0.917c0.807,2.296,1.199,4.593,0.824,6.675 c-0.814,4.545-3.486,6.847-7.812,7.391c-1.889,0.237-4.889-0.385-6.533-0.684c0.762,1.702,2.053,3.193,2.816,4.895 c3.658-0.529,6.369-0.454,8.336-1.374s4.076-2.981,6.6-3.854c2.525-0.873,4.777-0.859,7.539-1.29 c-2.176,1.875-3.604,3.751-5.777,5.626c1.594,4.633,3.188,9.265,4.781,13.897c3.379,2.114,6.549,3.228,10.807,5.838 c4.26,2.611,9.367,7.281,14.914,9.828s8.85,3.933,14.646,5.026c5.795,1.093,10.406,5.787,16.109,6.55s16.355,0.917,20.75,0.488 c4.99-0.487,11.473-3.062,12.055-8.533c-4.184,1.032-10.574,0.106-13.801-7.767c-1.432-3.496-0.73-9.925-2.922-14.059 c-2.191-4.135-5.246-5.462-8.896-10.556s-9.621-13.129-12.973-19.954c-3.35-6.824-4.139-14.554-6.973-20.669 c-2.834-6.114-7.109-11.053-10.422-15.766c-7.234-10.3-13.068-17.339-24.986-22.535c-5.732-2.499-12.258-3.165-18.387-4.748 c-2.494,1.117-5.914,2.351-6.521,5.268c-0.607,2.917,0.559,7.225,2.676,9.415c3.543,3.661,8.793,7.618,10.857,13.437 c1.326,3.734,1.711,16.252,0.562,19.649C372.234,192.824,369.463,194.957,367.16,197.306z M368.314,226.935 c-1.107,0.955-1.951,1.936-3.732,2.729c-1.779,0.793-4.209,0.998-6.57,1.588c3.311,5.154,6.789,10.362,9.961,15.781 c3.174,5.418,5.924,11.351,8.953,17.025c-0.143-3.252,0.049-6.719-0.424-9.758c-0.473-3.038-1.85-5.697-3.215-10.258 C371.924,239.481,370.246,233.276,368.314,226.935z M279.229,113.611c-0.467,5.07,0.391,12.996,1.441,17.96 c1.258,5.942,2.469,9.023,7.291,12.603c8.83,6.555,14.467,5.45,21.26,9.251c3.232,1.809,7.328,4.841,8.523,8.046 c1.195,3.205-0.789,6.685-3.24,8.053c4.287,0.638,9.094-4.195,7.088-9.157c-0.988-2.442-5.691-3.53-7.133-5.994 c-1.439-2.463-1.436-4.999-0.758-7.501c1.225-4.51,10.148-8.608,13.301-12.173c4.852-5.486,6.715-10.075,3.967-17.14 c-3.859-9.925-18.768-17.889-27.691-21.784c-4.086-1.783-6.377-1.91-9.564-2.865c6.525,3.824,13.404,6.87,16.705,15.418 c2.756,7.139,0.369,9.829,0.461,16.045c0.043,2.882,3.838,4.323,5.523,6.144c1.467,1.583,1.348,2.758,0.176,4.943 c-0.129-1.971-0.971-3.442-2.484-4.513c-2.498-1.771-5.189-1.39-6.52-5.021c-2.02-5.52,1.986-10.748-2.518-16.946 c-3.369-4.637-7.85-9.827-13.895-9.963c-2.861-0.065-5.012,0.367-8.068,1.271l-4.074-4.903l-0.094-0.064 c-8.287-7.563-13.957-13.796-25.582-18.994c-11.625-5.197-17.354-5.984-30.683-5.688c-13.329,0.295-26.557,1.41-41.995,14.723 c-15.437,13.313-55.224,64.292-64.873,70.744c-9.648,6.452-11.785,8.638-23.841,8.641c-12.056,0.003-30.872-17.05-31.609-38.362 c-0.738-21.313-1.034-28.888,13.781-54.563C88.94,46.146,115.78,38.262,135.694,35.6c19.915-2.662,31.882,4.352,46.613,4.385 c14.73,0.034,29.288-2.509,33.581-14.224c-2.101,1.251-4.916,2.661-12.832,2.246c-7.916-0.415-18.892-9.58-31.239-15.721 c-12.347-6.14-26.087-6.859-43.71-7.192S88.494,6.108,66.708,17.869s-36.657,24.24-49.293,47.258 C4.779,88.146,2.891,106.94,4.928,134.811c2.037,27.871,10.633,48.599,27.184,68.998s33.092,30.38,62.918,34.091l6.279-27.696 l-11.209,16.086l0.277-17.891l-10.139,12.581l-4.447-17.062l-8.214,13.679l-4.08-19.05l-11.903,9.627l3.768-15.719l-15.75,1.743 l7.235-10.926l-14.361,0.175l8.356-14.587L28.1,166.837l10.16-13.267l-15.6-4.625l12.916-12.368l-12.753-10.393l9.975-7.758 l-9.328-12.412l9.95-11.583l-3.714-15.296l8.449-7.365l2.515-17.481l9.482-4.762l8.158-13.646l15.079-1.601l7.44-12.274 l15.145,0.771l14.312-7.779l14.843,3.457l16.86-5.092l12.487,2.926l16.296,2.395l15.733,12.58l-24.133-8.424l-12.14,5.821 l-10.035-6.125l-6.909,4.693l-12.225,1.224L110.1,27.745l-7.992,9.756l-16.291,0.168l-5.811,13.143L65.52,55.894l-1.355,15.107 l-10.388,8.138l3.461,14.216l-8.971,14.765l6.882,12.915l-6.773,11.82l9.011,5.88l-2.044,18.998l12.532,3.158l2.823,14.093 l13.656-1.419l8.484,9.656l10.486-10.239c19.116-9.532,26.988-14.864,41.886-30.977c16.959-18.343,26.679-35.302,49.269-47.861 c16.202-9.008,29.417-12.25,47.617-9.105c17.088,2.952,22.81,13.202,35.395,24c1.334-2.415,1.605-3.055,3.803-4.833 C280.604,107.342,279.508,110.595,279.229,113.611z">
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s" values="12264;0" dur="25s" fill="freeze"  />
 </path>
</svg>
```